# How to enable the dropdown element in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am a newbie to bootstrap and now I wish to use its `navbar` and `dropdown` elements. When I copied the code of its example (see below) and click on the `dropdown` element, the expected dropdown menu doesn't appear,   which is different with its original page. Could you please tell me how to enable it? Thanks!

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: did you linked bootstrap js? and where is your starting nav tag?

Comment: @Leothelion Yes I did. it should be `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>`

Comment: m talking about js files. and check nav tag too.

Comment: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` @Leothelion These ones? I have done that.

Comment: Check this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/9u1tssha/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong order of javascript files, Bootstrap requires jQuery, just change order

```
<!-- FIRST jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<!-- THEN bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Next time take a look into developer console of your browser, bootstrap prints error message when jQuery isn't present

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery

You may also want to take a look at the [W3C html validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), it will let you know about html errors in your syntax, you will find out that there is no opening tag for `nav` (as @LeoTheLion has pointed out)

Comment: Also he is missing nav tag because of that he is not getting hamburger menu.

Comment: @user5779223 don't forget to add nav tag or you won't get menu icon in small screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `nav` tag.

Add this `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

as you have closed  but did not started so.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/9u1tssha/2/)

Comment: But the code is copied from the [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/?#navbar-default).

Comment: Oh I got you. My fault

Comment: Check back. you are missing main tag. see here https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You need this scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```